# Broken sub-/super-/overscripts after reopening file

Tags: cells, display, subscript

I'm entering something like $a_1$ by using `Ctrl -`. After I reopen the file, instead of a nice subscript, every  instance of $a_1$ now reads `Subscript[a, 2]`. How do I prevent this?

I also noticed that for some reason this problem does not appear for $\bar{a}$, entered with `Ctrl &` and then `_`. However, if I change the cell style to a text cell, then again I get `\!\(\*OverscriptBox[\(a\), \(_\)]\)` after reopening. Normal symbols like $\sigma$ or $\lambda$ work fine, so that must be something to do with subscripts, etc. Perhaps there are some different input types I'm not aware of?

Comment: So you're typing `Control -` in an input cell in a normal notebook? And then you save the notebook, close it, and reopen it? Do you quit the notebook interface (frontend) at all?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, sorry. I just write, save, reopen. I didn't do anything with the frontend explicitly. I also tried quitting the kernel before closing, but it doesn't help.

Comment: A screen shot of the before and after situation might explain a lot. I think you are leaving out certain details that are needed for someone else to understand what is going wrong.